# Gulp Not Watching

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

So consider the following gulp file:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var babelify    = require("babelify");
var watch       = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('make:engine', function() {
  return browserify({entries: [
        './src/index.js'
      ]})
      .transform("babelify")
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('engine.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('make:example', function() {
  return browserify({entries: [
        './examples/index.js'
      ]})
      .transform("babelify")
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('compiled-example.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/example/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['make:engine', 'make:example'], function(){
  return watch('*.js', ['make:engine', 'make:example']);
});
```

`gulp watch` spits out:

```
[15:06:01] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/ice-cream-engine/gulpfile.js
[15:06:01] Starting 'make:engine'...
[15:06:01] Starting 'make:example'...
[15:06:03] Finished 'make:example' after 1.57 s
[15:06:03] Finished 'make:engine' after 1.6 s
[15:06:03] Starting 'watch'...
```

In ANY js file, if I make an edit and save the file, the terminal doesn't update to say that it is making the engine or the examples.

The project directory looks as follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong such that it wont actually re-compile on ANY JS file change?

Comment: There's a good chance it (by default) requires NFS (google it) events to watch for changes, instead of scanning all files the regex matches every 0.x seconds (which takes a lot more cpu). If your OS (or VM) does not support this, you'll have to disable that option.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter This answer doesnt help at all. I am using MAC OSX and  your answer doesnt provide anything helpful.

Comment: Well that's a tad aggressive. OSX supports NFS events, so you're good there. Note sure how Gulp handles globs, but you can also try to use `**/*.js` or `src/**/*.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your screenshot, the only `.js` file that matches the glob you have passed to `watch` is `gulpfile.js`.

If you want to watch all `.js` files under the `src` and `example` directories, you could use the following:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['make:engine', 'make:example'], function(){
  return watch(['src/**/*.js', 'examples/**/*.js'], ['make:engine', 'make:example']);
});
```